# Keep axis value in rqt_plot

Tags: rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to keep axis value in rqt_plot for the next time (with either matplot or pyqtgraph) ?

When I reopen rqt_plot, it plot the last chosen topic but it does not keep the manual axis value that I have set previously.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146531/keep-axis-value-in-rqt_plot/) by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) on 2014-09-12**:
This was not implemented when you asked. But Austin has been working on related issues and it might be working as you want it now. If not please file as feature request.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-12**:
This shouldn't be hard to do, but it isn't implemented. You should file a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've submitted a pull request to rqt_plot which saves and restores the plot limits without breaking autoscaling: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/pull/292

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0